# How to eliminate the space after a line chart in Excel 2010

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010

I have problems to get rid of this space (the one marked in blue in my Excel 2010 line chart.

[image]

I noticed that it appears only if the line chart has more than one series.
Any suggestion?

Comment: This allowed my lines to reach the end, but I noticed your chart is a little different, so give this a try and let me know if it works. Double click on the X-axis, below the chart. On the Axis Options tab, at the very bottom set the "Position Axis" to "On tick marks"

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Could it be because the text goes that far? Try shrinking the X-axis labeling a bit.

Comment: Which labeling? I've removed the labeling. Under the chart there's just the legend. If I try to shrink it, nothing happens.

Comment: Have you verified the data selected for the chart doesn't include empty column/rows?

Comment: No, it doesn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved.
First I had to put a column with values from 0 to 8 and use it as the ticks of the X-axis.
Then, in X-Axis format, I had to select the date axis format.
Afer that I was able to decide where the axis should have started and ended.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem. When editing the chart data in excel, the range appeared to have no extra cells. However when I edited chart data through the other options (not excel), the ranged showed extra blank rows were selected. I changed the range there, and the extra space went away.

Answer (score 0):

The chart is being extended by the size of the x-axis labeling. Shrink the label text slightly, so that it isn't longer than your data points.

Comment: Which labeling? I've removed the labeling. Under the chart there's just the legend. If I try to shrink it, nothing happens.

Answer (score 0):

When you have a line chart and switch some of the lines to the secondary vertical axis, Excel also creates a secondary horizontal axis - but for some reason doesn't make this visible. The secondary horizontal axis remains set to 'between tick marks' after you set the primary to 'on tick marks', which is what causes this problem.

To fix it:

1. Switch on the secondary horizontal axis
2. Set its axis position to 'on tick marks' (the primary X axis also needs to be set to this)
3. Make the secondary horizontal axis invisible by setting the axis position to 'none' and selecting the line and changing it's outline color to 'no outline'